# Multipass on Windows & macOS only allows LTS images

Tags: windows-10, 19.04, macosx, raspberrypi

I am using Multipass (0.8.0) on Windows 10 (1903 18362.295) and want to create a 19.04 instance.

According to the documentation you can pass in any valid release name, but
`multipass launch disco` doesn't work:

```
launch failed: disco is not a supported alias. Please use `multipass find` for supported image aliases.
```

and `multipass find` only shows LTS images:

```
Image                   Aliases           Version          Description
16.04                   xenial            20190814         Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
18.04                   bionic,lts        20190813.1       Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
```

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:** I just tried on my MacBook (macOS Mojave 10.14.6) and got a similar result, the only difference being that `find` additionally shows 2 `snapcraft` entries.

**EDIT 2:** I have also tried on my Pi3 (Raspbian Buster) and get the expected output with disco available:

```
XXX@YYY:~ $ multipass find
Image                   Aliases           Version          Description
snapcraft:core          core16            20190819         Snapcraft builder for Core 16
snapcraft:core18                          20190820         Snapcraft builder for Core 18
core                    core16            20190806         Ubuntu Core 16
core18                                    20190806         Ubuntu Core 18
16.04                   xenial            20190814         Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
18.04                   bionic,lts        20190813.1       Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
19.04                   disco             20190814         Ubuntu 19.04
daily:19.10             devel,eoan        20190826         Ubuntu 19.10
XXX@YYYY:~ $ multipass launch disco
Retrieving image: 2%
```

So it seems to be a limitation with the Windows and macOS versions of Multipass, however, I cannot find any documentation anywhere which confirms this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have been in contact with the devs on their IRC channel and they have confirmed that Windows and macOS currently only support LTS versions. Support for non LTS is planned for the future.